# How to use DialogFragment for showing progress from an AsyncTask - without using ProgressDialog

Tags: android, android-asynctask, progressdialog

This site helped me already a ton for a year now and it's the very first time I cannot find an answer to my problem.

I am trying to publish a progress from an AsyncTask **without ProgressDialog**. The user just typed an address and I want to display places of interest within a certain radius from that address on a map and in a list. Therefor I need to get the addresses of these places from a database and calculate the distances, before I know which places I need to display on the map as markers.

While calculating the distances (in an AsyncTask), I would like to keep the user updated on the progress, before the markers can be finally displayed on the map.

The main two problems, that I have with my code:

- It will show and dismiss the DialogFragment properly, but will **not show the progress** (neither by the bar, nor by the numbers)
- **I do not want to use ProgressDialog**

Thanks a ton in advance, for any hint or suggestion!

My AsyncTask looks like this:

```
public class GetDistanceTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Integer,Integer>
{

private Location mSearchAddress;
private FragmentManager mSfm;
private ContentResolver mCr;
private static final String TAG = GetDistanceTask.class.getSimpleName();
private DialogFragment mDf;
private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;

public GetDistanceTask(FragmentManager sfm, ContentResolver cr, Location searchAddress){
    mSfm = sfm;
    mCr = cr;
    mSearchAddress = searchAddress;
}

@Override
protected Integer doInBackground(Void...voids) {
    int rowsUpdated = 0;
    int max = 0;
    final Uri locationUri = KitaContract.LocationEntry.CONTENT_URI;
    String selection = KitaProvider.sLocationKitaSelection;
    String[] args = new String[] {"3"};
    //All entries, unsorted
    Cursor cursor = mCr.query(locationUri, null, selection, args, null);
    if (cursor != null) {
        max = cursor.getCount();
        cursor.moveToFirst();
    } else {
        Log.e(TAG, "Cursor == null !");
        return 0;
    }
        do{
            double kitaLat = cursor.getDouble(COL_LAT);
            double kitaLong = cursor.getDouble(COL_LONG);
            int id = cursor.getInt(COL_LOCID);

            //make a Location-object from Kita's Lat & Long
            Location kitaAddress = new Location("kitaName");
            kitaAddress.setLatitude(kitaLat);
            kitaAddress.setLongitude(kitaLong);
            //calculate distance
            float distance = kitaAddress.distanceTo(mSearchAddress);
            ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
            contentValues.put(KitaContract.LocationEntry.COLUMN_DIST, distance);

            //add the distance to the kita entry in the database
            int rowUpdated =mCr.update(
                    locationUri,
                    contentValues,
                    KitaContract.LocationEntry._ID + " = ?",
                    new String[] {String.valueOf(id)});
            rowsUpdated += rowUpdated;
            publishProgress(rowsUpdated, max);
        }while (cursor.moveToNext());
    cursor.close();


    return rowsUpdated;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    // instantiate ProgressDialog
    mDf = (DistanceProgressDialogFragment) mSfm.findFragmentByTag("dpdf_tag");
    if (mDf == null){
        mDf = new DistanceProgressDialogFragment();
        mSfm.beginTransaction()
                .add(mDf, "dpdf_tag")
                .commitAllowingStateLoss();
    }
    else mDf.show(mSfm, "dpdf_tag");

    if (mDf != null) {
        mProgressDialog = (ProgressDialog) mDf.getDialog();
        mProgressDialog.setProgressNumberFormat("%1d/%2d Kitas");
    }
}

@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
    mProgressDialog.setMax(progress[1]);
    mProgressDialog.setProgress(progress[0]);
    super.onProgressUpdate(progress);
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Integer rowsUpdated) {
    if ( mDf != null) {
        mDf.dismiss();
    }
}
```

My DialogFragment like this:

```
public class DistanceProgressDialogFragment extends DialogFragment
{

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setCancelable(false);
}



@NonNull
@Override
public ProgressDialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity(), getTheme());
    dialog.setTitle("Kita Guide");
    dialog.setMessage("Suche Kitas in der Nähe");
    dialog.setIndeterminate(true);
    dialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
    return dialog;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`dialog.setIndeterminate(true);` indicates that progressbar should keep running forever.

Comment: Thank a lot! This was a step stone to fixing it. My main error was that I always got an "null pointer exception" on "mProgressDialog.setMax(progress[1])" because apparently I called "mDf.getDialog()" before onCreateDialog() in the DialogFragment was executed. Calling "mSfm.executePendingTransactions();" did the trick for me.